# Send data to Zoopla in c#

Tags: c#

I am working on window service to send data to zoopla. 
https://realtime-listings.webservices.zpg.co.uk/docs/latest/documentation.html

But how to send data, I did't find any code sample for c#. If anyone have any sample that I can try that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Zoopla provides you an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface), likely an [HTTPS one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API). You won't find any "Zoopla with C#" tutorial since all you have to do is making HTTPS requests.

So all you need to know is :

1. What is Zoopla's API [maybe here ?](http://developer.zoopla.com/home)
2. Make HTTPS requests [maybe there, if you use .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)

Comment: through API .. list data can't be sent that why i mentioned other link in question

Comment: I got it : just read [this section and the next one](https://realtime-listings.webservices.zpg.co.uk/docs/latest/documentation.html#messaging) and [this doc](http://developer.zoopla.com/docs).. a bit long but you'll get how to send/update data into zoopla ;)